# Subtracting my number class (List of integers) is crashing my android app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, game-development

I made my own number class https://pastebin.com/Hhp3CbB8

```
IdleNumb sub(IdleNumb? number) {
    if (number != null) {
      for (int i = number.numbs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (numbs[i] < number.numbs[i]) {
          numbs[i + 1] -= 1;
          numbs[i] = numbs[i].toInt() + 94868329;
        }

        numbs[i] = numbs[i].toInt() - number.numbs[i].toInt();
        fixNum();
      }
    }

    return this;
}
```

whenever I perform the sub function it seems to crash my app. all the other functions seem to work fine it's only when ever sub is called that the app crashes. Most problems I have had, had a debugger printout and the app closes in the emulator. With this crash the emulator freezes up altogether and the debugger just stops without printing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want with this class, but the error is in this line:

```
numbs[i + 1] -= 1;
```

If your result is a negative number then it throws an Exception

For example:

```
IdleNumb a=IdleNumb(6);
IdleNumb b=IdleNumb(7);

IdleNumb e=a.sub(b);
```

You try to decrement the array i+1 element but the array is only i long so you get a RangeError.

Comment: There is extra logic else where that ensures that the number is using the sub method is the larger of the two numbers. I haven't had any errors subtracting numbers that have a list length of 1, it crashes when I get into numbers that have a longer list length.

Comment: Do you have any exact example numer? I tried with several numbers and combinations, but it worked with all.

Comment: It seems to crash if both numbers are over 94868329